# Do I need a visa for my days in Canada when traveling to the US using the VWP?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, norwegian-citizens

I am an Norwegian citizen and this summer, I am going on a 4 week holiday in the US. For the most part, I will be staying in the US, but I want to drive over the border on a day trip to see Canada. The plan is to drive from the US to Canada, then to fly from Toronto back into the US. I have been approved for the US Visa Waiver Program, but have not gotten anything for Canada. Do I need a Canada visa, and are there any complications regarding my Visa Waiver when I leave and re-enter the US?

Adrian A. Andersen

Comment: Which country are you a national of?

Comment: I am a Norwegian citizen, who have gotten my VWP-request accepted.

Comment: You mean you have gotten your ESTA approved. VWP participation is a status that _countries_ apply/netgotiate for.

Comment: You don't need a visa, and if you will be driving to Canada you do not need an eTA. Read http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html

Comment: Yes, I guess that is the right term for it.

Comment: Ok, i'll look into that article. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

[Norwegian citizens do **not** need a visa for Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-result.asp?country=NO&result=2&q3=)

However, bear in mind that you're admitted to the US for 90 days, and that that clock continues while you're in Canada and on re-entry to the US

Comment: Don't forget to mention the Canadian ETA (which is effectively a visa), although it's not needed for overland trips.

Comment: @JonathanReez I' purposely did not mention it because the question is about driving to Canada. I also disagree with you about it being a visa - the way I see it, like ESTA, it's an electronic passport registratiom